# How to convert string date (25.04.2016) to date format (mm/dd/yyyy)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, parsing, format

I have string date (25.05.2016) ,i want to convert it into (mm/dd/yyyy) format in VB.net. 
Please suggest solution.

Comment: what happens if you need to store the timezone.. then that's out the window. Either use the UTC format or ISO8061 date format.

Comment: also, "Please suggest solution" .. we're not a code shop for nothing, you clearly have not learnt what it takes to research, i.e. read the MSDN documentation which is quite extensive. Very poor question that reeks of laziness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) with the format you need to get the string into a date variable, then [.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert to another format:

```
Dim dateString As String = "25.05.2016"
Dim dateFormat As String = "dd.MM.yyyy"
Dim dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Debug.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

The list of custom datetime formats [can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing though. Since you don't have time part and you know that you have direct conversion from DD.MM.YYYY to MM.DD.YYYY, you can do it even "mechanically"

```
Dim converted As string = String.format("{1}/{0}/{2}", "25.05.2016".Split(".".ToCharArray()))
```

Fun, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

VB.Net has the DateTime class with which you can use the methods like Convert.ToDateTime(String), DateTime.Parse() and DateTime.ParseExact() methods for converting a string-based date to a System.DateTime object.

Example as shown below:

```
Dim inDate As String = "25.05.2016"

Dim outDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(inDate)

MsgBox(oDate.Month & "/" & oDate.Day & "/" & oDate.Year)
```

Comment: OP asked for form mm/dd/yyyy, you have the day and month in reverse.

Comment: I was about to edit it .. now take a look , and remove the downvote

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` is not a safe conversion for all locales and your output will not always give a 2 digit day or month as requested